# Create a service using Automator to compile .tex file in Mac

Tags: compiling, automation, latexmk

I'm using *Mac OS 10.9.3*, *TeXLive-2013* and *Scrivener* to write my papers. I'd like to use Apple's Automator in order to create a service (available from the Finder's right-click menu over a file) called "Compile TeX file" that runs a simple command using the selected file as an *input*.

Exemple:

1. Inside a folder (/Volumes/Data/TeX_docs/) I've an *exemple.tex* file created by Scrivener that is ready for compiling with LaTeX.
2. I'd like to right click this file and from the Finder's Service menu choose the option "Compile TeX file"
3. Once chosen, this service will execute the command `latexmk -pdf -bibtex exemple.tex` and so compile the .tex file inside the same folder, creating a .pdf file (This Terminal command is working perfectly right now, so the need to automate this action!)
4. After compiling the .tex file, a dialog box appears and asks if I want to delete all the temporary files with a `Yes` or `No` option. If `Yes` is chosen, it deletes all TeX temp files (.aux,.bbl,.bcf,.fdb_latexmk,.fls,.log,.out,.run.xml) and keep only the original exemple.tex and the new exemple.pdf file. Otherwise, it does nothing more and I have all the files in the end!

Comment: I give up. Debugging this is impossible when all I get is a "some error occured".

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3crkhyf9cez09eu/AABo33ISjsW4xEwh8Hw_w8_ba

If someone wants to give it a shot. My problem was to actually get alle the files in the same directory as the .tex-file, something that proved pretty damn hard (for me atleast).

Answer (score 2):

This is not the optimal solution, but it's working for now. Here is the Automator window:

[image: Automator actions]

The first shell script compiles the `.tex` file using the sequence `pdflatex - biber - pdflatex` and contains the following code:

```
for f in "$@"
do 
    file_ext=${f##*.}
    if [ "$file_ext" = "tex" ]
    then
        foldername=$(dirname "$f")
        export foldername
        filename=$(basename "$f")
        filesimple=${filename%.tex*}
        cd $foldername
        /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex "$filename"
        /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/biber "$filesimple"
        /usr/local/texlive/2013/bin/x86_64-darwin/pdflatex "$filename"
    else
        echo $f n\'est pas un fichier TeX
    fi
done
```

The second shell script deletes all *temp* files and opens the `.pdf` file. It contains the following code:

```
for f in "$@"
do 
    file_ext=${f##*.}
    if [ "$file_ext" = "tex" ]
    then
        foldername=$(dirname "$f")
        filename=$(basename "$f")
        filesimple=${filename%.tex*}
        cd $foldername
        rm $filesimple.aux
        rm $filesimple.bbl
        rm $filesimple.bcf
        rm $filesimple.blg
        rm $filesimple.log
        rm $filesimple.run.xml
        open $filesimple.pdf
    else
        echo $f n\'est pas un fichier TeX
    fi
done
```

I'm still waiting for a better solution using the `latexmk` command!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the prettiest solution, but it gets some of the way towards what you wanted (i.e., using `latexmk` and a confirmation dialog):

First, your first script can be substituted for something like this:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    file_ext=${f##*.}
    if [ "$file_ext" = "tex" ]
    then
        foldername=$(dirname "$f")
        filename=$(basename "$f" .tex)
        cd "$foldername"
        /usr/texbin/latexmk -pdf -bibtex "$filename"
        open "${filename}.pdf"
    else
        echo $f n\'est pas un fichier TeX
    fi
done
```

Note that I've added the open command to the first script, so that the second script is *only* responsible for cleaning up the temporary files. Also, if you want to simplify things further, you could create a `.latexmkrc` in the same directory as your generated TeX files with the following:

```
$pdf_mode = 1; # equivalent to -pdf
$bibtex_use = 2; # equivalent to -bibtex
```

And then simplify the `latexmk` command to `/usr/texbin/latexmk "$filename"`. Then, before the second `Get Finder Items` step, add an `Ask for Confirmation` step. where you can enter the message text and change the buttons to "Yes" or "No". NB, that the "OK" button should be changed to "Yes", assuming you want "Yes" to be the default option.

Finally, you can change your second script to something like this:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    file_ext=${f##*.}
    if [ "$file_ext" = "tex" ]
    then
        foldername=$(dirname "$f")
        filename=$(basename "$f" .tex)
        cd "$foldername"
        /usr/texbin/latexmk -c "$filename"
        rm -f "$filename".bbl
        rm -f "$filename".run.xml
    else
        echo $f n\'est pas un fichier TeX
    fi
done
```

`-c` is the option to run `latexmk` in clean-up mode, but it won't delete your pdf. Note that I still needed to manually delete the `.run.xml` and `.bbl` files. I don't quite understand why `latexmk` isn't cleaning up the `.bbl` file.

Something closer to a solid solution would likely have to involve some more scripting and breaking this up into multiple workflows to, e.g., gracefully handle the case where compilation fails and display the log file for the user. Plus, having an independent service which can clean-up the TeX auxiliary files might be nice. But, as far as simplicity goes, this is the best I can think of.